# How do i pass the correct context into new RelativeLayout? android java

Tags: java, android, android-layout

heres my function

```
public void populateList(View v){
    ViewGroup LLview = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
    RelativeLayout row1 = new RelativeLayout(this);
    LLview.addView();

}

View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lesson_list, container, false);
    populateList(v);
```

the 'this' in line 3 gives an error: RelativeLayout (android.context.Content) in relative layout cannot be applied to (ian.marxbrothers.LessonList)

how am i suppose to create a new RelativeLayout? i just want to add it to LLview

this method is in a fragment class LessonList which eventually gets put into MainMenu Activity after an Adapter.

Thanks for any help ive been stuck trying to google this for hours now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void populateList(View v){
ViewGroup LLview = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
RelativeLayout row1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
LLview.addView();
}
```

This usually works for me or `getActivity().getBaseContext();`

Answer (score 1):

If you're inside of a Fragment, use `getActivity()` to get the context.

```
public void populateList(View v){
ViewGroup LLview = (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout);
RelativeLayout row1 = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
LLview.addView();

}
```